# What is the path used for the HD wallet in Bitcoin Core 0.13?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, bip32-hd-wallets

I heard that the next version of Bitcoin Core will support HD wallets.

What will be the path used for that implementation?

Comment: FYI for BIP44 support on Bitcoin derivation path one can use the Breeze wallet (a light wallet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.13 (current most recent release) supports HD wallets (if you create a new wallet with 0.13 it will use HD by default, <0.13 wallets will keep the non HDness).

You can disable the HD feature in >=0.13 with `-usehd=0` (or `usehd=0` in `bitcoin.conf`).

It does use only hardened private key derivation.

The keypath-scheme is `m/0'/0'/k'`.

BIP44 is not supported right now. It makes little sense (weak security) to use public key derivation (BIP44 does) together with a possibility to export private keys.

Comment: could you please tell me what 0 and k stand for? which one is index?

Comment: `m/0'/0'/k'`, means " derive first hardened child of master key = `m/0'`, then, derive again the first hardened child key of that key (`m/0'/0'`), then, derive another child key with an up-counting index for your receiving addresses (`m/0'/0'/0'` for first address, `m/0'/0'/1'` second, `m/0'/0'/2'` thirds, a.s.o.)